# OpenShift, how do I give myself clutser-admin?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift, redhat, openshift-client-tools

I just started using OpenShift and have permissions problems. I am on the free trial for OpenShift 4.3.3 and cannot get my containers to run as root. I am the only user on my instance and I have admin, but it says I need cluster-admin to run the containers as root?

I tried running:

```
oc policy add-role-to-group cluster-admin anyuid
```

and that returned:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "cluster-admin" is forbidden: user "hustlin" (groups=["system:authenticated:oauth" "system:authenticated"]) is attempting to grant RBAC permissions not currently held:
{APIGroups:["*"], Resources:["*"], Verbs:["*"]}
{NonResourceURLs:["*"], Verbs:["*"]}
```

Going through OpenShift Online -> Administrator view -> User Management -> Roles -> cluster-admin -> Role Bindings, it states:

```
Restricted Access
You don't have access to this section due to cluster policy.
Error details

rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "hustlin" cannot list resource "rolebindings" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
```

I feel like it should not be this difficult for me to run a container as root. Just testing out OpenShift and I haven't been able to successfully run a single container on the platform, they all eventually go to `CrashLoopBackOff`.

Yes, I did try the:

```
oc login -u system:admin
```

command and it prompted me for my password before returning:

```
error: username system:admin is invalid for basic auth
```

I even tried following [this guide from the OpenShift blog](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-any-docker-image-running-in-your-own-openshift-cluster/), but it would not recognize `oadm`.

Comment: "Free trial"...are you referring to OpenShift Online Starter via https://manage.openshift.com?

Comment: @WillGordon it is the Starter Plan and can be found here: https://www.openshift.com/products/online/ .

Comment: Starter is a multitenant cluster, so there are many users all running on that cluster. It would be a huge security risk to allow users to have `cluster-admin` access. The same reasoning applies for allowing privileged containers. You can refer to the docs (https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-specific-guidelines) on how to create a non-privileged container.